# Do scanners really work better using Windows drivers?

Tags: windows, scanner

I'm deciding what software to use to scan a large number of photographs and came across this article:

> It’s a bummer I can’t use Ubuntu with my Canon flatbed scanner. Luckily I hadn’t scanned too many photographs before discovering the issue. My lesson here is be cautious of Linux driver support with third party vendor hardware. Just because I might be able to get something working on Linux or it’s advertised as supporting Linux, doesn’t mean it works as well as other operating systems. Even though developers might use MacOS 2X more and Linux 10X more compared to an average user, the reality is Windows still holds dominate desktop and laptop market share so it’s not surprising hardware vendors are still investing more resources into their Windows drivers.
> — [Don't Use Linux to Scan Photographs - Digital Tidying](https://www.digitaltidying.com/dont-use-linux-to-scan-photographs/) — 2019

Is that true in general; does the scanning software available for Windows produce better scans?

I'm not trying to start another war here; responses should be facts, not opinions.

Comment: I'm not sure about "better" scans but Windows scanning applications (part of drivers) often have some features not found in SANE.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, the claim in the article is that the raw scan isn't as good because of the device drivers, nothing to do with individual applications or features.

Comment: I generally prefer not to argue with belligerent open source aficionados because they are capable of turning arguments against Open Source inside out.

Comment: What "issue"? Has original poster tried anything to diagnose/fix his problem? Which scanner manufacturer & model do you want to use? Check out the "SANE" (Scanner Across Now Easy) project. `man -k sane`. My HP flatbed scanner was Plug 'n Play.